# How to Populate multiple divs using jQuery's ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, html

I was trying to get my head around jQuery's Ajax. I have a page made up of a number of divs. I also have an XML document generated from a MySql resultset.

In the jQuery function below I am able to populate the titleDiv with data. The question I have is how do I populate the other divs on the page without having to build the page from scratch? I hope this makes sense......

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getData").click(function(){
        var data = "";
        $.get("phpAjax.php", function(theXML){
            $('row',theXML).each(function(i){
                var title = $(this).find("Title").text();
                var rating = $(this).find("Rating").text();
                data = data + title; 
            });
            $("#titleDiv").html(data);
            $("#ratingDiv").html(?????);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u try with??
first decalre variable

```
 var title='';
 var rating ='';
```

& then inside `each`

```
   title+ = $(this).find("Title").text();
   rating+ = $(this).find("Rating").text();

    $("#titleDiv").html(title);
    $("#ratingDiv").html(rating);
```

Comment: Sure did...didn't work. I thought that would make the most sense too. I did an alert(rating) and that contained the correct value. But it still hasn't populated the div. I did manage to populate the rating div with data (title) so its not an issue with that either...

Comment: do u have multiple divs  or only two div `title` and `rating`??

Comment: nice one, I got it, my variables were local to the function. I had to declare them outside like you said. Cheers!!! And I have loads of divs just shortened it down to 2 for posting sake. thanks again

Comment: NEver mind - I see you understood diEcho's point about declaring the variables outside the scope of the function. I thought you said you had done so and it didn't work.

Comment: @Tim, thanks Tim, the "sure did...didn't work" was to a post diEcho had that he subsequently edited to include the local variable issue. Thanks again for taking the time.